# Onclick of a button in javascript does not do anything on IE9

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-9

The issue is,

I am trying to click on the function set, and when i click Ok afer i get the alert ,it does not fill the text field test for me.This works fine on IE 7 and IE8.I was trying to test on IE9 and it does not do anything.Can anyone point me in the right direction.

```
   function setTest(x)
   {
document.add(x).value = "this is a test value"; 
   }

    </SCRIPT>
```

The HTML code is as follows

```
    <td>
   <input type="text" name="test" id="test" size="10" value="<?php echo $test;?>"> 
   <input type="button" value="FILL" class="submit" onClick="if( confirm( 'Are you sure you want to set this field.') ){ setTest('test'); }">
    </td>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you setting the value ?  I don't see a "document.add": is "add" a form ?

Comment: a) what does `document.add(x)` do? b) try using `onclick` in lower case (this may not be the problem, but still a standard way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've no idea what `document.add` is supposed to do, but if you want to set the value of that `input` field it looks like you actually want `getElementById`:

```
function setTest(x) {
    document.getElementById(x).value = "this is a test value"; 
}
```

[**Example on jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/EA8Gh/).

Comment: @swathi: Does my [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/EA8Gh/) work for you in IE9? It definitely works for me.

Comment: I tried opening it on IE9,it works fine,but when i try to use it in my application,it does not work.I will try to see if theres something else which is trying to block it.THank you.